# why do i get an array out of bounds array when printing from arraylist?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, error-handling, indexoutofboundsexception

i cant seem to understand why the array i am trying to print throws an array out of bounds error when i try to append it to a JTextArea.

Both arrays have been initialized to start at zero.

```
          private ArrayList<String> UniResponse = new ArrayList(0);
          private ArrayList<String> CHOICES = new ArrayList(0);
```

uniPicksString, UniResponse, and CHOICES are arrays that have been passed from a different object, however they have also been initialized to start at 0;

this method returns the elements of the array list as a string type

```
String receiveAdminResponse() {
    Iterator<String> itr = UniResponse.iterator();
    String hold = null;
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("\n  inside Student class = pringint decision array");

    for (count = 0;count < UniResponse.size(); count++) {
        System.out.println(UniResponse.get(count));
    }

    while(itr.hasNext() && count<UniResponse.size()) {
        hold = UniResponse.get(count);  
    }
    return hold;

}
```

this is the method that creates the string that is appended to JTextArea

```
String returnProfile() {
    String studentInfo =FAMILYNAME+", " + "average = " + AVERAGE + " \n";
    String uniPicksString ="";

    for (int i = 0; i<CHOICES.size(); i++) {            
        if(i<CHOICES.size() - 1) {
            uniPicksString = uniPicksString +CHOICES.get(i)+ ": " + ApplicantArray.get(i).receiveAdminResponse();//"admin decision, " ;
        }else {
            uniPicksString = uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(i)+ ": " +  ApplicantArray.get(i).receiveAdminResponse();//"admin decision" + "\n" ;
        }   
    }   
    return studentInfo  + uniPicksString + "\n";
}
```

is it possible to create a try catch statement that will ignore the error thrown and print the arraylist?

any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to start following Java naming conventions. It's important to get into good habits as early as you can. Next, could you provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets, and make sure you show the exact exception, including the stack trace? You're calling `ArrayList.get()` 6 times in the code you've shown, and we can't see which one is throwing an exception.

Comment: most probably your `ApplicantArray` is SMALLER than `CHOICES` array

Answer (score 2):

As the comments say, most likely the `applicantArray` is smaller then `choices`.

Still, `count` equals `UniResponse.size()` therefore the `while` loop condition evaluates to `false` from the beginning and so you return a `null` value.

No that it changes anything, it's hard to understand what you need...

> is it possible to create a try catch statement that will ignore the error thrown and print the arraylist?

`try / catch` does not get along with *ignore the error*

---

Also, the `if` statement in your second function is useless. You do the very same in thing in both the `if` and the `else` body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the following while will be executed. before at the end of for loop the count value is equal to UniResponse.size(). So the condition will fail.

> while(itr.hasNext() && count

I think you are getting index out of bounds on the method returnProfile().
You are iterating through CHOICES and inside that you are using another variable ApplicantArray. Is CHOICES and ApplicantArray are same size ? If not and ApplicantArray size is less than CHOICES then you will fall into out of bounds exception.

Comment: ApplicantArray is an arraylist of objects, each of which hold an array CHOICES those objects have made. ArrayList.get(i).returnProfile() was intended to individually return the CHOICES made by the objects.

Answer (score 0):

How J J says I think that this condition:

```
while (itr.hasNext() && count<UniResponse.size())
```

makes that "hold" stay empty, because you use "count" before. The "for" sentence finish because "count" is equal to UniResponse.size(). In addition think that you don't need to use itr.hasNexT(), so you can do all in the for loop. I would write this:

```
String receiveAdminResponse() {
  String hold = null;

  if (UniResponse.size() > 0) {
    System.out.println("\n  inside Student class = pringint decision array");

    for (int count = 0;count < UniResponse.size(); count++) {
      System.out.println(UniResponse.get(count));
      /* If you use '=' you are setting the variable to the last value 
      of UniResponse.get(count) */
      hold += UniResponse.get(count) + ", "; // ',' or '\n" the separator you want  
    }
  }

  return hold;
}
```

Try this, for **returnProfile** method:

```
String returnProfile() {
  String studentInfo =FAMILYNAME+", " + "average = " + AVERAGE + " \n";
  String uniPicksString ="";

  if (ApplicantArray.size() < CHOICES.size()) {
    System.out.println("ApplicantArray size is lower than CHOICES (" + ApplicantArray.size() + ", " + CHOICES.size + ").");
  }
  else if (ApplicantArray.size() == CHOICES.size()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < CHOICES.size(); i++) {            
      if(i < CHOICES.size() - 1) {
        uniPicksString += uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(i) + ": " + ApplicantArray.get(i).receiveAdminResponse() + ", " ;
      }else {
        uniPicksString += uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(i) + ": " +  ApplicantArray.get(i).receiveAdminResponse() + "\n" ;
      }   
    }   
  }
  else System.out.println("ApplicantArray size is bigger than CHOICES (" + ApplicantArray.size() + ", " + CHOICES.size + ").");

  return studentInfo  + uniPicksString + "\n";
}
```

For better performance use StringBuilder instead + or +=

Good Luck and sorry for my english level!

:)