# why does the following keep returning an out of bounds error?

Tags: java, arraylist

Please help my figure out why this keeps throwing an out of bounds error. i tried making a separate loop keep track of AdminDecisions

```
String returnProfile() {

    String uniPicksString ="";
    String studentInfo = null;


    //for(int i = 0; i<ApplicantArray.size(); i++) {
        studentInfo =FAMILYNAME+ ", " + "average = " + AVERAGE + " ";
            for (int j = 0; j<CHOICES.size(); j++) {            
                if(j<CHOICES.size() - 1) {
                    uniPicksString = uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(j)+ ": " + " admin decision, " ;
                }else {
                    uniPicksString = uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(j)+ ": " + " admin decision"  + "\n";
            }   
        }   
    //}
    return studentInfo  + uniPicksString + "\n";
}
```

the following code shows the desired out put but i cant return it as a string

```
 String printProof() {
 // System.out.println("from inside the student class");
    String temp=null;
    d = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int j = 0 ; j<1; j++) {
        System.out.print("\n >>printProof<<  " + FAMILYNAME+", " + "average = " + AVERAGE + " ");
        for (int i = 0; i<AdminDecision.size(); i++) {
             //System.out.println(AdminDecision.get(i));    
             //temp = CHOICES.get(i)+ ": " + AdminDecision.get(i) + ", ";
            if(i<CHOICES.size() - 1) {
                temp = CHOICES.get(i)+ ": " + AdminDecision.get(i) + ", ";
            }else {
                temp = CHOICES.get(i)+ ": " + AdminDecision.get(i) + "\n";
            }
            System.out.print(temp + " ");
            d.add(AdminDecision.get(i));
        }
    }
    return temp + "\n";
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the exception?  How many elements are in `CHOICES` and how many in `AdminDecisions`?

Comment: uniPicksString = uniPicksString + CHOICES.get(j)+ ": " + " admin decision, " ;

Comment: when i replace "admin decision, " with AdminDecision.get(i) it throws the exception

Comment: Add the stacktrace, please. It will show where the error occurs. What are the values of CHOICES and FAMILYNAME? Please provide a runnable example with input values and stacktrace.

Comment: if(j<CHOICES.size() -1) is used to format the output string. if it is the last AdmidDecision it wont print the extra comma at the end. i will post stackTrace shortly

Comment: So, can you show the actual code that throws the exception?  Rather than showing code that only throws the exception if you change something?  Because right now, it's too confusing with the different ArrayList variables.  You have AdminDecision, but also ApplicantArray.  Are they the same thing?  Please make it easy for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Firstly, are the two blocks of codes two separate questions? Secondly, does your application has multiple thread?

Comment: the two blocks are should provide the same output, except return profile should print to a jtextarea. the second block of code prints to console. ApplicantArray is an arralist of student objects, and AdminDecision is an arrayList contain acceptance/reject decisions from a list of universities selected by the student

Comment: ApplicantArray and AdminDecision are not of the same length. for every object held in ApplicantArray, 3 AdminDecisions should be printed

Comment: You have basically already asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49168420/why-do-i-get-an-array-out-of-bounds-array-when-printing-from-arraylist) .... and you did not get a real answer because of lack of details... same thing here